# Evaluate ${\large\sum_{k=1}^n} \sum_{i=1}^k i{k \choose i}{{n - k - 1} \choose k - i - 1}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

> Evaluate
>
> $$a_n = {\large\sum_{k=1}^n} \sum_{i=1}^k i{k \choose i}{{n - k - 1} \choose
> k - i - 1}$$

I derived this sum when working on the following problem

> Find the total number of $1$'s in the [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) of $n \ge 2$.

WolframAlpha states that $a_n = 2^{n - 3}(n + 2)$ but I'm unable to come up with a proof of this claim. I've been trying to think of this combinatorially; for example, as the number of subsets in a set of $n-3$ elements where there are $n + 2$ sets to choose from. However, I haven’t been able to relate this to the sum above.

**Comments:**

- Please view this as if you did not know that the sum evaluates to $2^{n-3}(n + 2).$ That is to say, inductive proofs aren’t viable unless they can be reasonably conjectured.
- Please do not provide alternate solutions to the problem of finding the number of $1$'s in the compositions of $n$. I am specifically looking for a method to evaluate the sum.

---

**Side Query:**
Strangely when I input values for $n$ into the summation, WolframAlpha gives me a value that is $n$ higher than the evaluated expression. If you are aware of why this is the case, please feel free to comment.

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the Wolfram Alpha code?

Comment: @Jacobiman [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BSum%5Bi*%5C%2840%29k+choose+i%5C%2841%29*%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29n+-+k+-+1%5C%2841%29+choose+%5C%2840%29k-i-1%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bi%2C1%2Ck%7D%5D%2C%7Bk%2C1%2Cn%7D%5D)

Comment: [A045623](https://oeis.org/A045623) may be of some help

Comment: From playing around with different values of $n$, it seems that difference in Wolfram Alpha's evaluation of the series and then the expression is always $n$. Maybe the correct answer is $2^{n-3}(n+2)+n$ and there is a small mistake in Wolfram Alpha for these types of series? However, I am no expert on Wolfram Alpha and computational math.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n\geq k\geq  2$, by [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity),
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} i{k \choose i}{{n - k - 1} \choose
k - i - 1}=k\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} {k-1 \choose i-1}{{n - k - 1} \choose
k - i - 1}=k\binom{n-2}{n-k}.$$
Therefore
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=2}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} i{k \choose i}{{n - k - 1} \choose
k - i - 1}&=\sum_{k=2}^{n}k\binom{n-2}{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}(n-k)\binom{n-2}{k}
\\&=n\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\binom{n-2}{k}-(n-2)\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}\binom{n-3}{k-1}\\
&=n2^{n-2}-(n-2)2^{n-3}=(n+2)2^{n-3}.
\end{align}$$
which is the same formula given at [OEIS A045623](https://oeis.org/A045623).

Comment: @BeKind Now it is correct.